# Differential pair circuit

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, differential

I have the following differential pair circuit that is designed to have a diff gain of 4 V/V and a power consumption of 1mW. The transistor should be biased to have a Veff=0.3V and should have a length of 0.25um. With uCox = 270 and Vt=0.45V. I should determine W in the transistors and the values of RD and Ibias. Do you have any idea of how can I find these parameters? I have some equations but I got to a point that doesn't make sense. Where should I account on the consumption power?

[image]

Comment: The circuit is not included.

Comment: No schematic, a diffpair by itself cannot have  a voltage gain as it has current outputs. What is the load of the diffpair ? What is Veff ? Assume the transistors are in saturation mode and use the appropriate formula.

Comment: Veff in this text book is Vov = Vgs-Vt

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems it was easier than thought. I was stacked in a point. If I have the total power consumption (1mW) and the source voltage (1,8V) I can get the bias current and work with it.